# sizing reactjs images to window size

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-component

I am working on a portfoilo-building project, and I have a component with 5 images.  I want the images to have the height and width of 1/5 the width of the screen.  How can I accomplish this?

```
class TopPictures extends React.Component {


  render() {
    const imagestyle = {
      height: "200px",  //this is wrong
      width: "200px",
    };
    return(
      <div>
        <img src = {image1} style = {imagestyle} alt="image1"/>;
        <img src = {image2} style = {imagestyle} alt="image1"/>;
        <img src = {image3} style = {imagestyle} alt="image1"/>;
        <img src = {image4} style = {imagestyle} alt="image1"/>;
        <img src = {image5} style = {imagestyle} alt="image1"/>;

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [viewport units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/) to size these images:

```
const imagestyle = {
  height: "20vh",  
  width: "20vw",
};
```

`vh` and `vw` stand for viewport height and viewport with respectively, and they are used to represent a percentage of the full viewport height/width. For instance, `20vh` represents 20% of the viewport height.